# How will the Ubuntu Phone SDK impact desktop development

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-phone, qt5

If I was to develop an application for Ubuntu after the Ubuntu Phone announcement, I would be concerned with several issues. I know that these things will not change immediately, but I'm thinking about the strategic decision to ensure good support from Canonical.

- Will QML/QT be the way forward now also for the desktop environment?
- Is Quickly now a tool of the past?
- What languages will be the preferred languages? Is C++ and JavaScript the way for the future while Python and Vala might not be the most strategic choices?
- How will this affect existing APIs? Will the traditional model with libraries change?

Comment: Why should it have an impact at all?, the Desktop and in Ubuntu's case specifically Unity, is not even developed  for the same devices, nor with the same toolkits. The target audiences are way different even when they want to use one Interface for everything.

Answer (score 6):

- Qt has been a first-class toolkit on Ubuntu for several cycles, and will likely become one of the most important toolkits for cross-formfactor development on Ubuntu.  But no existing languages or toolkits are being deprecated on the Desktop.
- Yes, Quickly will be less important as a tool for developing Ubuntu SDK apps.  The Quickly developers have decided that it would be better to build the same functionality into QtCreator itself, rather than build Qt/QML templates for Quickly.
- QML (which can contain Javascript) will be the recommended language and toolkit for cross-formfactor development in Ubuntu.  Python, Vala, C and C++ will continue to be available, though the extent to which they are recommended for new development may change.
- Existing APIs should not be affected by the Ubuntu QML Toolkit, though which ones we recommend will change depending on which ones best support our various formfactors.

I hope this answers your questions and concerns.