# QML/Qt Development path verses "Quickly" and Gtk

Tags: application-development, gtk, qt, qml

It seems like recently the path Ubuntu is moving towards is to have code developed with QML and Qt, and that appears to sync with their move to be able to target tablets, phones, TV devices and the desktop.  Information on this can be found here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

However, they also seem to be concurrently pushing Quickly/Python as the development platform for the desktop specifically and this relys on Gtk, as can be seen here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

If I want my application to have longterm viability and to be portable across platforms which should I be investing my time in? Will QML/Qt eventually be pushed as the Ubuntu SDK solution and reliance on Gtk be dropped, or will there be a move to broaden development choices by allowing Gtk apps to be written in QML, and allow Gtk to run on tablets and phones?

It would be helpful to know what the future roadmap is so developers don't invest time and resources down a deadend path...

Comment: Tried same kind of question, but it got closed down. Good luck  :)

Comment: is the answer on your question not satisfying, tronda? http://askubuntu.com/questions/243585/how-will-the-ubuntu-phone-sdk-impact-desktop-development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've now reviewed the content on the App developers site so that it is clearly stated that the focus and the recommended way to write Ubuntu apps is the Ubuntu SDK.

While Quickly will still be available in the archives, and you will still be able to write Python + GTK applications with it, the only supported and recommended technology to develop applications that can run on multiple devices will be the Ubuntu SDK.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: In other words now Qt is the recommended toolkit for developing apps for ubuntu , right?

Comment: But why there is no official quickly template for Qt?

Comment: The Ubuntu SDK is the recommended way to develop apps for Ubuntu. It is based on the Ubuntu UI Toolkit, which is in turn based in Qt Quick 2. We no longer recommend Quickly as the tool of choice to develop new apps for Ubuntu, hence there will be no Quickly Qt template.